# How to transform lambda function to multi-argument lambda function and how to rewrite or approximate terms?

Tags: formal-grammars, lambda-calculus, natural-language-processing

I am trying to do the formal semantics (Montague grammar, abstract categorial grammar) of natural language and encode the sentence `John is boss`. The type system has to primitive types - `e` for entity and `t` for Boolean type. `John` has type `e`, `is` has type `(e->t)->(e->t)` and `boss` has type `(e->t)`. The the full sentence is translated as the lambda expression:

```
(is(boss))(John): t
```

I don't like the chaining of functional application and more intuitive presentation could be by introducing new function `IS` of type `(e, (e->t))` and hence the expression could become:

```
IS(John, boss): t
```

And by moving boss from the argument the function index we can arrive to the standard predicate expression with new predicate-function:

```
IS_BOSS(John): t
```

I have two questions regarding this example:

- Does standard lambda calculus have multi-argument functions? As I guess that these calculus have such function by currying and hence the real type if `IS` is `e->(e->t)->t`. So, this part seems to be already answered.
- And now is the main question - **does lambda caluclus allow do function transformation** - e.g. is there some operation which transforms `is:(e->t)->(e->t)` into `IS:e->(e->t)->t`? **Are there some apparatus/algorithms/methods how can I express function** `is` **via the function** `IS` **and how can I transform terms involving** `is` **into terms that does not contain** `is` **and that contains** `IS`**?** Are there some rewriting apparatus available for this in lambda calculus?

This question is inspired by the book https://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-Formal-Semantics-Introduction-Mathematical/dp/0748640436 and uses notions and notation from this book.

Important note. I do not expect that `is` and `IS` are identical functions (but I would be glad to consider the case when some kind of identity is assumed as well). I expect that `is` is more general function (that is used for the processing of the raw text) and that I try to express it using more specialised function `IS` (which can convey more specific meaning, e.g. borrowing from pragmatics (branch of lingustics): I can analyse context and determine that in this context such detalization is desirable). Maybe rewrite operation should be used but maybe some other tools should be used - simply - how to transform term using these functions? **Maybe I am just trying to approximate function** `is` **with function** `IS` **(of different type!) and** `is`**-terms with** `IS`**-terms? Are there such notions, theories?**

*Maybe I should look to higher-order rewriting of lambda terms? Is there example available how my terms could be rewritten inside such framework?*

Comment: What is higher order rewriting?

Comment: It is rewriting with rules that contain bound variables. Teresa Rewriting book has chapter 11 about higher-order rewriting.

Comment: All of your terms are closed though. Which part from Andrej's answer doesn't meet your need? Your source and target terms are definitionally equal. I do not see much complexity.

Comment: I am suspicious about possibility to use re-currying in the general case. In this case it is simple, because 'is' uses e and e->t functions and they should be reordered only when moving to 'IS'. But, generally, the more complex re-currying may happen that can require to re-curry inner functions and I doubt that that is possible.

Comment: You should explain that situation in details. I still agree with Andrej. As long as it's about shuffling the order and form of syntax, it's just a matter of cutting and uncurrying.

Comment: OK, I will think about it once more in the coming days (I hope to move to more involved structures ASAP and experience challenges). At present I am concerned about how to do this practically. Coq has no such rewriting facilities, so I should parse code and manipulate AST, but those are the other questions.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [currying and uncurrying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Lambda_calculi) which transform functions of type $A \times B \to C$ to functions of type $A \to (B \to C)$, and vice versa. Currying takes `IS` to `is`, while uncurrying takes `is` to `IS`. This is a standard and very basic technique in $\lambda$-calculus. There are many manifestations of currying and uncurrying, for instance in arithmetic it is the identity $c^{a \cdot b} = (c ^ b) ^ a$.

It is largely a matter of taste how you write multi-argument functions. The uncurried form $A \to (B \to C$ has the advantage that you can apply the function only to the first argument. In your case `is boss` is a useful concept which is expressible very neatly. With the other function you have to write `λ x . IS (boss, x)`.

Note however that sometimes people do *not* include product types $A \times B$ in their versions of $\lambda$-calculus, in which case of course currying is unavailable (but nothing much is lost).